# Custom wp-content/upload image page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, .htaccess

I've been looking for a way to make a custom direct access images on wp-content uploads folder since a year ago, but I still didn't found how to serve / display image in wp-content/uploads folder using custom script (maybe php)

Please take a look at my screensshot here : http://prntscr.com/30sdb8
you can see this wp-content/uploads are still have some additional code, and even this page source are hidden with an image (the same image)
is there anyone know how to do that on a worpdress website?

Thanks for answering my question

**Updated**

because of some unclearly information in my previous question here I try to explain as clear as I can.

In a default wordpress website if a user direct access an image from wp-content/uploads/ directory (for an example : www.domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/image-name.jpg )
there will be only an image and a blank background, but in my screenshot example you can see that there are some additional code in header and footer. 
my question is how to make modification like that in wordpress? so I can display a header and of footer on my wp-content/uploads/ Url pages

ps : the website I mean is lincah.com , you can go to google image, site:lincah.com then click on 1 image on the search result you'll be brought to the page I mean.

I hope thats clearly enough.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You need to explain what you mean by "custom" and "direct access". Your screenshot doesn't explain anything, its just a screenshot of an image on a page.

Comment: So we should figure out what the problem is, based on a couple of firefox windows showing a picture of a car?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is unclear, In default if users access wp-content/uploads/ images , they will be shown only an image, but in this case, that image was shown in a custom page, you can see there are header on there, and also footer at the bottom.
what I mean by custom is changing how the way image displayed on a browser in wp-content/uploads/ url  in a direct access.. I hope that clearly enough, if someone want to know detail of this case, please go to google image, then type site:lincah.com , click one of the image and thats the point.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I could make out is you need a PHP script that could fetch all the images from uploads folder and display on the page.

```
<?php
    $images_list = glob("wp-content/uploads/" . "*");

    foreach($images_list as $image) {
       echo '<img src="' . $image . '" /> <br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: How could I implementing this code into wordpress website?

Comment: @octopusaga  Just copy paste this code on the page you want to display the images and change the path. Eg. "wp-content/uploads/03". That's it.